# php - Codeigniter JSON extra characters

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-3

I have this code.

```
public function view_users()
    {
        $this->db->select('mem_account_no, mem_acc_username, mem_acc_password');
        $this->db->from('member_account');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        echo json_encode($query);
    }
```

the result I get with this is :

```
aha[{"mem_account_no":"4","mem_acc_username":"win","mem_acc_password":"chi"},{"mem_account_no":"5","mem_acc_username":"ropenrom24","mem_acc_password":"pamela005"}]
```

It has this " aha " extra characters at begining of the json and I dont know why.

Comment: If you comment out `//echo json_encode($query);` do you get _aha_?

Comment: `grep -R 'aha' *`  I get random characters all the time when I type faster than my windows can switch.

Comment: I still have the aha when I commented the echo json_encode($query);

Comment: Then it's somewhere else in your code.

Comment: yeah thanks I already found it